# Odd error with Ustream JSON API and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to run the following jQuery:

```
var query = 'http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/masaiblog/getValueOf/status?jsonp=?';

$.getJSON(query, function(data)
{   
    if (data['results'] == 'live')
    {
        alert('ITS LIVE!');
    }
});
```

Very simple, right? It goes to the Ustream API, gets the JSON data, checks to see if the `results` value equals `live`, and alerts the user if it is. However, when I run this, instead of working as it should, I get an error:

```
{"results":"live","msg":null,"error":null,"processTime":true,"version":"mashery-r10"}

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I'm using very similar code to Justin.TV and that works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the API call should return a JSON object wrapped inside a function, so you have to append `&callback=?` to your URL.

`http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/masaiblog/getValueOf/status?callback=?`